# How to make lis stack (without vertical spacing)

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to line li so they stack. The problem that I am running into besides how to word my question is how do I get lis so the space under each li is the same. On my left side, I get large spacing like:

```
---------------
CONTENT
---------------




---------------
MORE CONTENT
---------------
```

While on my right side, I have

```
---------------
RIGHT CONTENT
---------------

---------------
MORE RIGHT CONTENT
---------------
```

I would like to make it so the left side fits like the right. It seems that the left side sticks to how the right side stacks.

```
---------------            ---------------
LEFT CONTENT               RIGHT CONTENT
---------------            
                           ---------------

---------------            ---------------
MORE LEFT CONTENT          MORE RIGHT CONTENT
---------------            ---------------
```

CSS:

```
#l, img{
    width: 400px;
    background-color: rgba(144,144,144,.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px black;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    }
dl{
    color: yellow;
    font-size: 30px;
    }
li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 50px;
    }
li a {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 100px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<li class="searchable" data-index="NAME"><dl>
    <dt><img class="l" src="IMAGE"></dt>
    <dt>NAME</dt></dl></li>
```

Result I am looking for:

```
---------------            ---------------
LEFT CONTENT               RIGHT CONTENT
---------------            ---------------

---------------            ---------------
MORE LEFT CONTENT          MORE RIGHT CONTENT
---------------            ---------------
```

~Xplo

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a padding style for the class(s):

```
li.searchable{padding-bottom:20px;}
```

I assume that it is the correct class. . .

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work out. I'm going to try to see if I can redo my CSS and try to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any div in your code but you can set their position with position : absolte, setting their top and left according to your will. It is useful to visit [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp), but I just tell you search more about it.